# Actualizar todos los registros de una tabla mediante un sp

Tags: sql, stored-procedure, update

Se tiene una tabla con columna **salario**, y columna **bonificación**.

La columna salario tiene datos numéricos, la columna bonificación es de tipo numérica pero se encuentra vacía.

Es posible crear un procedimiento almacenado mediante el cual se pueda insertar datos a toda la columna de bonificación, un porcentaje del sueldo (teniendo como condición rangos ejemplo: sueldos de 1000 a 2000 50%, de 2001 a 5000 30%, mayores de 5000 20%)??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si, podrías hacer un query como este e incluso meterlo en un stored procedure:

```
UPDATE miTabla
SET bonificacion =
    CASE
        WHEN sueldo BETWEEN 1000 AND 2000 THEN sueldo * .5
        WHEN sueldo BETWEEN 2001 AND 5000 THEN sueldo * .3
        WHEN sueldo > 5000 THEN sueldo * .2
        ELSE 0
    END
```

¡Suerte!